# Is there a more Pythonic way to do string case insensitive comparison with None check

Tags: python-3.x

```
@staticmethod
def case_insensitive_comparison(str1, str2):
    if str1 == str2:
        return True
    elif str1 is None or str2 is None:
        return False
    else:
        return str1.upper() == str2.upper()
```

Is there a better way to do string comparison with none val can be expected?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Can you please say more about that, or point to an article that explains why? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html just two sentences.

Comment: @AndyLester From the Unicode Standard (mentioned in the docs you linked): "Case folding is related to case conversion. However, the main purpose of case folding is to contribute to caseless matching of strings, whereas the main purpose of case conversion is to put strings into a particular cased form." Python's `casefold` lacks some sophistication (as compared to e.g. NFKC_Casefold) but is preferrable over `lower` and `upper` which are *not* intended for caseless comparison at all; see the example in your link as an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from typing import Optional

def foo(str1: Optional[str], str2: Optional[str]) -> bool:
    # This is incorrect because an empty string will return false
    # return (str1.upper() if str1 else None) == (str2.upper() if str2 else None)
    return (None if str1 == None else str1.casefold()) == (None if str2 == None else str2.casefold())
```

In this case, `str.casefold()` will always be invoked, which may effect the performance.

Comment: U can't compare null to string so it will fail

Comment: Did you really try my code? [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yP2TvKb9Pd/) is my test cases and results.

Comment: This gives wrong results for empty strings. `foo("", None) != case_insensitive_comparison("", None)`

Comment: YES! you are right, I forgot that. I will change my answer, thanks for your _hacking_

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic:

```
str1 = str(str1 or '')
str2 = str(str2 or '')

return str1.casefold() == str2.casefold()
```

or

```
return str(str1 or '').casefold() == str(str2 or '').casefold()
```

Comment: This gives a different result for `None, None`. The code in the question evaluates that as `True`.

Comment: Hell, you're right. Can't think of a more reader-friendly way to tell the compiler what to do. I guess this could work in implementations where at least 1 value is not None. Though, if speed isn't a priority, I'd just go with `return str(str1).casefold() == str(str2).casefold()`